# How and why do TypeInitializationExceptions crash dotnet on linux, and how can I prevent this defensively?

Tags: .net, typeinitializationexception

I've been using `dotnet` on linux for a bit now and I've noticed that my `dotnet` process crashes hard and produces a core dump whenever a `TypeInitializationException` occurs.

Of course the solution is to fix the underlying type initialization issue, but I am wondering *why* this sort of exception is not one from which `dotnet` can recover, and 2) whether there is anything I can do to prevent a `dotnet` crash if such an exception occurs? Is there something worse about unhandled `TypeInitializationException` as opposed to other unhandled exceptions?

### example

For instance, one of the API calls to my application eventually hits the following lines of code.

While load-testing this API call in particular I started seeing my `dotnet` crash.

```
using (var gThumbNail = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(scaledMap)) {
    gThumbNail.FillRectangle(new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.FromName(backgroundcolor)), 0, 0, width, height);

    int masterWidth = large.Width;
    int masterHeight = large.Height;
    int heightOffset = 0;
    int widthOffset = 0;
    int oldHeight = height;
    int oldWidth = width;

    // Scale or crop desired size thumb from master image
    if (cropthumb == false) {
        var pluckRect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(large.Width / 2 - width / 2, large.Height / 2 - height / 2, width, height);
        var cropRect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
        gThumbNail.DrawImage(large, cropRect, pluckRect, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    } else {
        gThumbNail.DrawImage(large, widthOffset / 2, heightOffset / 2, width, height);
    }
}
```

You can reproduce this by instantiating a new `System.Drawing.Graphics` without all this particular code - **on a Linux machine without GDI installed.** Sometimes to reproduce the crash I have to hit it with some load (5 or 10 concurrent users).

When I inspected the core dump, I found:

```
Nested exception -------------------------------------------------------------
Exception object: 00007fcab86500b0
Exception type:   System.TypeInitializationException
Message:          The type initializer for 'Gdip' threw an exception.
InnerException:   System.DllNotFoundException, Use !PrintException 00007FCAB864AAC8 to see more.
StackTrace (generated):
    SP               IP               Function
    00007FC994FF5A70 00007FCFCD621866 System.Drawing.Common.dll!Unknown+0x56
    00007FC994FF5AF0 00007FCFCD621735 System.Drawing.Common.dll!Unknown+0x95
    00007FC994FF5B50 00007FCFCD61EADA Acme.App.dll!Unknown+0x9ca
    00007FC994FF5F30 00007FCFC5D88ACF System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()+0x1f
    00007FC996FF9F40 00007FCFC5DCBEB7 System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)+0x57
    00007FC996FF9F60 00007FCFCD5B8CD3 Acme.App.dll!Unknown+0x343
    00007FC9F3FFBAF0 00007FCFCD621735 System.Drawing.Common.dll!Unknown+0x95
    00007FC9F3FFBB50 00007FCFCD61EADA Acme.App.dll!Unknown+0x9ca
    00007FC996FFA040 00007FCFC5D88ACF System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()+0x1f
    00007FC9F3FFBF30 00007FCFC5D88ACF System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()+0x1f
```

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve]? My experience is that it depends on where the exception is thrown.

Comment: @JonSkeet, sure... I am not sure how much this helps.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not a [mcve]. We have no context of where that code exists within your application. We don't know what's calling it, what the threading model is, etc - nothing.

Comment: (I've just tried a small console application deliberately throwing a TIE and it failed exactly how I'd expect it to, without bringing down the whole CLR.) I'd really like to be able to reproduce your specific issue, by copy/paste/compile/run.

Comment: Ok, I see. I'll work on it and get back to you. I think the only way to really achieve a minimal and verifiable example that is to create a little ASP.NET core app from scratch with the same issue.

Comment: Right - knowing it's ASP.NET Core is a good starting point :)